# A sequence/queue converges Does my answer correct?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does this queue converge to 1 ? [image]

what i've done is telescope sum and the ive got $(\ln(n^5+n^4)-\ln(n^5+1))n$ and then ive used Euler limit and then ive got $\ln(e^1) = 1$.
Is this the correct thinking ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Doesn't it telescope to $(\ln(n^5+n^4+1)-\ln(n^5+1))n$?

Comment: What is a "queure"?

Comment: @saulspatz then the queue disconverge ?

Comment: No, your basic idea is correct, you just need to do a little more work.

Comment: How can this be closed?  The OP clearly indicated his approach to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic approach is right, but you made a small error when you added up the series.  It telescopes to $$
(\ln(n^5+n^4+1)-\ln(n^5+1))n=n\ln\left(1+\frac{n^4}{n^5+1}\right)$$
When you made your error you got $$n\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)$$ instead, so you were able to use the fact that $$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\rightarrow e\tag1$$
That was a good idea, but you have to do some more work in reality.  The easiest way I've found is to write it as $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac1{n+n^{-4}}\right)}{1/n}$$ and use L'Hôpital's rule.  One application of the rule gives the limit $1$, so the sequence converges to $e$.

We can do this without L'Hôpital's rule.  When $x>0$ we have $\log(1+x)<x.$  (To see this, let $f(x)=\log(+1x)-x$ and note that $f(0)=0,\ f'(x)<0$ for $x>0$.) Therefore,$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\ln\left(1+\frac{n^4}{n^5+1}\right)\leq  
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^5}{n^5+1}=1$$ 
In a similar way, one can see that  $\log(1+x)>x-\frac{x^2}2$ for $x>0$ so that $$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\ln\left(1+\frac{n^4}{n^5+1}\right)\geq
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^5}{n^5+1}-\frac n2\left(\frac{n^4}{n^5+1}\right)^2=1$$

Comment: It's simpler.  Note $$\log\left(1+\frac{n^4}{n^5+1}\right)=\frac1n+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$Now multiply be $n$ and take the limit.

Comment: @MarkViola Yes, I had just come to that myself, but now I don't have to edit the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much ! is there a way of thinking without L'Hopital(Haven't learned it yet) ?

Comment: @Sababoni The simplest way is using Mark Viola's comment, but I don't imagine you've gotten up to that either.  I added a way that doesn't use L'Hôpital's rule.  This is essentially establishing Mark's comment.  I indicate how to prove $$x-\frac{x^2}2<\log(1+x)<x$$ for $x>0$ and use that to evaluate the limit.  I'm afraid it's a little like pulling a rabbit out of a hat, though.